# Hallar los primeros N números primos en JS

Tags: javascript

Me he topado con un ejercicio en JS donde se debe hallar los primeros N números primos, he buscado algunos códigos por ahí pero ninguno ha terminado de solucionarmelo. Muestro cómo lo he realizado yo, para saber si hay algún código más optimizado y que necesite menos iteraciones para llegar al mismo objetivo. Gracias de antemano

```js
function exercise() {
        let number1 = parseInt(prompt("Introduce un número"));
        let primesArray = [2];
        let prime = true;
        let primeAdd = 0;

        for(let i = 1, y = 3; (primesArray.length) < number1; i++, y = y + 2) {
            prime = true;
            let limit = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(y));
            
            for (let x = 2 ; x <= limit; x++){
                if (y%x == 0) {
                    prime = false;
                    
                    break;
                }
             }

             primeAdd = y;

             if (prime) {
                 primesArray.push(primeAdd);
             }

            }
            console.log(primesArray);
       }
       
       exercise();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se si es mas corto o si es mejor, pero me puse a probar y llegue a esto, seguramente se pueda seguir mejorando.

Le agregue un poco de html para que se pueda visualizar aca directamente.

```js
function ListarPrimos(limit,primos){
  console.time("primos")
 for ( i=3, d=0; primos.length< limit; i=i+2, d=0 ){
  for ( aux=3;d<1 && aux<= Math.sqrt(i);aux+=2 ){ d += i%aux == 0 }
  d == 0 && primos.push(i)
 }
 console.timeEnd("primos")
 return primos
}

function insertarPrimos(){
    document.getElementById("primos").innerHTML = ListarPrimos(
      parseInt(document.getElementById("cantidad").value), [2]
  ).join("<br>")
}
```

```html
  <label>Ingrese la cantidad de números primos que desea conseguir</label>
  <input type="number" id="cantidad">  
  <button onclick="insertarPrimos()">Generar primos </button>
  <div id="primos"> </div>
```

Comment: Agradezco mucho tu aporte Facundo, voy a revisar las iteracciones que realiza el código para poder llegar al objetivo, también veo que utilizas algunos conceptos que yo aun desconozco y los acabo de descubrir. Gracias de antemano, te responderé con el resultado

Comment: He probado las iteracciones del código y realiza más iteraciones que el código anterior para llegar al objetivo. He obtenido algunas sugerencias por parte de amigos y voy a ir probando a implementarlas para intentar mejorarlo. Subiré aquí el resultado

Comment: Si, me parece que el truco es usar el limite de la raiz que utilizas en tu codigo, fijate si podes agregar eso a mi versión y con eso deberia limitar la cantidad de iteraciones.

Comment: @GonzaloPlazaRueda Fijate si ahí bajo el numero de iteraciones y se volvió mas eficiente, saludos.

Comment: Ahora si está mucho mejor, el código es más limpio y se bajan aún más las iteraciones. Muchas gracias por tu aporte, me ha ayudado de mucho